# Sympy evalf doesn't work with 1 variable subs() in 2 variable expression

Tags: python, sympy

For a college project in python using Sympy, i need to evaluate the output of a 2 var symbolic function after partial substitution, eg:

> f =  (x-1)/sqrt((x-10)^2+(y-10)^2) / x = 1  =>  f = 0

If i use an 1 var func, it works fine:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> F = 1-x
>>> F.evalf(subs={x: 1})
0.e-125
```

But in the case of a 2 var function, subs doesn't seem to do the substitution right:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,y = symbols('x y')
>>> F = (x-1)/sqrt((x-10)**2+(y-10)**2)
>>> F.evalf(subs={x: 1})
(x - 1.0)*((x - 10.0)**2 + (y - 10.0)**2)**(-0.5)
```

I expected F = 0 since x = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a sympy expert but I found a counter example when the value of `y` makes the expression non-zero:

```
>>> F.evalf(subs={x:1,y:float("nan")})
nan
```

when `y` is `nan`, the result is not zero. So it's not possible to simplify the expression not knowing the value of `y` (note: sympy happily evaluates `F.evalf(subs={x:1,y:oo})` to 0 even if the result should be nan as well)

Comment: you are right i didnt think of that, but i found out if i just:
    >>> F.subs(x,1)
    0
now if i explicitly substitute y = nan only then i get the nan answer
    >>> F.subs(y,nan)
    nan

Comment: I think you could write your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above if y = nan creates a math exception, and so the substitution never happens.
But i found out if i just use subs then i get what i want:

```
>>> F.subs(x,1)
0
```

now if i explicitly substitute y = nan only then i get the nan answer

```
>>> F.subs(y,nan)
nan
```

Im guessing evalf is just checking for more exceptions before it evaluates the substitution.